# Is windows OS in raspberry pi 5 can be controlled by using android mobile as display?

Tags: android, windows, mobile, raspberry-pi, display

I am currently working on a project on raspberry pi 5. I am using windows OS in Pi since some python applications are made to work only in windows.

So for using windows in raspberry pi 5, Do I needed to buy a separate HDMI display or can I use an android mobile phone as a display?

Comment: Android phones never allow HDMI input. The only way to use it remotely would be a remote control software like RDP, VNC, ...